# How can I correctly configure redirects in Spring Security with a Vue.js Frontend to work with OAuth2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, spring-security, oauth-2.0

We have a use case where a user receives a link per email. For example the following link:

http://localhost:8080/#approveData?uploadId=134

This will work fine as long at the user has already signed in using our SSO which is OAuth2 based. I cannot get the redirects to work correctly however in the case where we need to authenticate and authorize the user.

The first Problem is going to this page has exactly the same effect as going to

http://localhost:8080/

Clicking the link in the mail or going directly to the home page of the app at "/" simply result in a 403 and do not successfully redirect to the sign on page of the Auth Server.

If I navigate to http://localhost:8080/login/ I am correctly redirected to the Authentication Server which is running on localhost:9000. I can log in but then I am sent to the http://localhost:8080/#/ path which now loads correctly but I would like to be automatically redirected to the following page

http://localhost:8080/#approveData?uploadId=134

I am using Spring Boot as an OAuth2 Client and Vue.js for the frontend.

Below is the relevant Spring Configuration:

```
@EnableOAuth2Client
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(),
            BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.csrf().disable();

}

private Filter ssoFilter() {

    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter webEamFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login");
    OAuth2RestTemplate webEamTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(webEamNext(), oauth2ClientContext);
    webEamFilter.setRestTemplate(webEamTemplate);
    UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(
            webEamNextResource().getUserInfoUri(),
            webEamNext().getClientId());
    tokenServices.setRestTemplate(webEamTemplate);
    webEamFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);



    return webEamFilter;
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("webeamnext.client")
public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails webEamNext() {

    return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("webeamnext.resource")
public ResourceServerProperties webEamNextResource() {
    return new ResourceServerProperties();
}

@Bean
public PrincipalExtractor webEamNextPrincipalExtractor() {
    return new WebEamNextPrincipalExtractor();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(
        OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {

    FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registration.setFilter(filter);
    registration.setOrder(-100);
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    loggingFilter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
    return loggingFilter;
}
```

}

This is my application properties file:

```
##Oauth Settings
security.basic.enabled=false
webeamnext.client.accessTokenUri=http://localhost:9000/auth/oauth/token
webeamnext.client.clientId=SampleClientId
webeamnext.client.clientSecret=secret
webeamnext.client.userAuthorizationUri=http://localhost:9000/auth/oauth/authorize
webeamnext.resource.userInfoUri=http://localhost:9000/auth/user/me
```

It seems to me that spring is unaware of the Vue.js components or URLs completely and it thinks the only URL is /. All other parts of the URL after the # are only existing in the world of Vue.js

This is my Vue.js Router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import openCalculation from '@/components/openCalculation.vue'
import checkoutData from '@/components/checkoutData.vue'
import appProCircle from '@/components/appProCircle.vue'
import appBDchange from '@/components/appBDchange.vue'
import testDB from '@/components/testDB.vue'
import approveData from '@/components/approveData.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router ({

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'appProCircle',
            component: appProCircle,
        },

        {
            path: '/openCalculation',
            name: 'OpenCalculation',
            component: openCalculation,
            props: true
        },
        {
            path:'/checkoutData',
            name:'CheckoutData',
            component: checkoutData,

        },

        {
            path: '/testDB',
            name: 'testDB',
            component: testDB
        },

        {
            path: '/approveData',
            name: 'ApproveData',
            component: approveData
        },

    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an Interceptor for the application.

Here is a quick sketch of how the interceptor needs to look like,

```
@Component
public class SecurityProtection extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public static final String SESSION_USER = "SESSION_USER";
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public SecurityProtection() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (null == request.getSession().getAttribute(SESSION_USER)) {
            String redirectURL = "/login";
            response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
            return false;
        }
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

}
```

Then dont forget to include in your security config.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityProtection securityProtection;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(securityProtection);
    }

}
```

Comment: This works somewhat but the problem is when I paste the URL http://localhost:8080/#approveData?uploadId=134 I cannot figure out how to get the part of the request after the '#' symbol. The frontend is a Single Page Application based on Vue.js. The #approveData component is a vue component and the whole application lives on the '/' path in Spring. Is it possible to get the part after the '#' from 'HttpServletRequest request'. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately the part after `#` is only available to the browser and not to Spring Boot on the server side. In such cases, I would recommend you to make the `index.html` and the angular's other static content  unauthenticated.  Let Angular startup check for authenticated session by making call to API and if it is failed, then put the `location.href` value to `sessionStorage` and redirected the user to login page. After successful login, redirect user back to the `#part` by resetting the value from `sessionStorage` I recommend you to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/23784932/3560866