# Mongoose find with project to rename

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to rename the return of some of my variables using project after a find, but it doesn't work, like this:

#Vars: email, age, name

```js
    this.userModel.find(usersFilterQuery).project({age: 'ageUser'});

 Is it just possible? Or just using aggregate?
```

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate of: [How do I rename fields when performing search/projection in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784370/how-do-i-rename-fields-when-performing-search-projection-in-mongodb)

Comment: No, I saw this post, but it is using aggregate. Sorry if you can't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is not possible in `find()` query. So, you should use the aggregate query if you want MongoDB to do this for you:

```js
this.userModel.aggregate([
 {
   $match: usersFilterQuery
 },
 { 
   $project: {
     age: '$ageUser'
   } 
 }
]);
```

---

There is more thing that you can do. You can set virtual property in your Schema model, and Mongoose will create these for you on the fly (they will not be stored in the database). So, you will tell Mongoose to add `age` property to each document that would be equal to the existing `ageUser` property.

You can check more in the [official docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html).